# How to set timer that do a specific task after the time is finished

Tags: java, timer

I'm trying to do a simple program that ask you to remember 30 numbers after 3 minutes. I have done everything, also the timer, in the examples I put 5 seconds. But I don't know how to save in memory the numbers, because the array that contains them is in another class. To create the timer I found this method, but not sure if is correct. So at the end of the program I get the array generated from the pc that is empty and the result is to lose all the points.

```
public class Test {

  // variables for the class
  int[] Array = new int[30];
  int ArrayNumUser[] = new int[30];
  int x;
  public static Test R = new Test();
  Timer timer;
  static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  static String verifica;
  char p;

  // Constructor timer
  public Test(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new NumUser(), seconds * 1000);
  }

  public Test() {
  }

  // Generate numbers with an array
  public String GenerateNum() {

    for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
      x = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0);
      Array[i] = x;
    }
    System.out
        .println("Rember this numbers, you got 3 minutes to complite the challenge");
    return Arrays.toString(Array);
  }

  // Save the numbers in an array
  public class NumUser extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
      int y;
      System.out.println("Insert the numbers you remember..");

      for (int i = 0; i < ArrayNumUser.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Insert the number: " + (i + 1));
        y = scan.nextInt();
        ArrayNumUser[i] = y;
      }

      // Check the numbers are equals to the arrays given
      System.out.println("Enter 'x' to confirm");
      String ver = scan.next();
      char confirm = ver.charAt(0);
      if (confirm == 'x') {
        int points = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
          int p = Array[i];
          int t = ArrayNumUser[i];
          if (p == t) {
            points++;
          } else
            points--;
        }

        System.out.println("Yours points: " + points);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Array));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ArrayNumUser));
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    R.GenerateNum();
    new Test(5);
  }
}
```

Comment: >>  but not sure if is correct: Why do you think that? Did you get an unexpected result?

Comment: Enter 'x' to confirm
x
Yours points: -30
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

Comment: I get this... the array with all the 0 is the array that initially is given to me from the pc.. and the array with 3 are my numbers (just putted 3 to save time) the problem is that I'm not able to see the first array with all numbers that I should remember and I get this one empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it other way:
1. in Test() constructor generate array,
2. write schedule method in test which schedules timer

```
  public Test() { GenerateNum(); }
  public void schedule(int sec) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new NumUser(), seconds * 1000);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().schedule(5);
  }
```

Comment: it works, but at the begin I get double array now... The pc give me two array and it saves just the second... why?

Comment: Rember this numbers, you got 3 minutes to complite the challenge
[2, 2, 8, 3, 3, 0, 1, 7, 4, 6, 1, 6, 7, 2, 1, 1, 8, 2, 1, 9, 2, 2, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 1, 4, 4]
Rember this numbers, you got 3 minutes to complite the challenge
[3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 8, 5, 0, 4, 1, 2, 5, 9, 9, 6, 5, 2, 6, 9, 2, 1, 1, 2, 9, 8, 9, 2, 5, 4, 8]
Insert the numbers you remember..

Comment: I think maybe you have started two tests. One here `public static Test R = new Test();` within the scope of the class and then in `main` you call another `new Test(5)`. Since `GenerateNum()` is now a part of `Test()` it's called twice. You don't need this one `public static Test R = new Test();`.

Comment: Right! line:
`public static Test R = new Test();`
should be removed

Comment: yep, perfect you are right! thank you very much guys ;)